# Make Equal size strings by adding spaces

Tags: java, string

I have a list of strings. I want to make all strings of equal length.
What I've tried so far is

```
    int largestLineLength = 0;

    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        String s = list.get(i);
        list.remove(s)
        list.add(s.trim());
    }
    //get the largest line
    for (String s : list) {
        int length = s.trim().length();
        if (length > largestLineLength) {
            largestLineLength = length;
        }
    }

    for(String s: list){
        while(s.length() != largestLineLength){
            //add spaces to s
        }
    }
```

**Requirements:**

1. Make all the lines with equal length by adding spaces
   between the words.
2. No spaces should be appended before or after the line.
3. Spaces should be evenly distributed to make all lines equal

For example

```
Luke Skywalker has returned 
to his home planet of Tatooine 
in order to — okay, you 
know what, we don't care. 
We were thinking of not even 
doing this one.
```

should be

```
Luke  Skywalker  has  returned 
to his home planet of Tatooine 
in   order  to  —   okay,  you 
know   what,  we  don't  care. 
We  were  thinking of not even 
doing this one.
```

**P.S. Last line is an exception**

Comment: When you remove an item from the list, you should be using iterator. It's not safe to remove an element without it.

Comment: Also your problem is not well defined; Where do you want to add spaces? What if there are 10 spaces need to be inserted and your sentence has 6 words? Where the spaces should be appended? Between which words?

Comment: spaces should be equally distributed to make all lines equal

Comment: @Sorter This would make sense only if you are using monospaced fonts.

Comment: You might need to think about what *equal distribution* means, here, because the exact number of spaces needed between each word maybe a fractional number. A solution that ends every line left and right flush thus might need to generate different spacing between each word.

Comment: Its supposed to be 'evenly distributed'

Comment: @Sorter did you read my answer?!

Comment: @Lrrr I tested the solution. its not working.

Comment: @Sorter you could leave a comment at least to let me know what is wrong with my solution!

Comment: @Lrrr I'm sorry. I was trying to fix it.

Comment: @Sorter I just posted my full main code and my out put, please check this out.

Comment: @Sorter I even posted online version of my code [here](http://ideone.com/UPqzl9) that you could test it online!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple solution is to find difference between longest line and current line. And find out every word in your line, then distribute your spaces after each world.

I have implemented this solution, and it is available online [here](http://ideone.com/UPqzl9) take a look at my solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    list.add("Luke Skywalker has returned");
    list.add("to his home planet of Tatooine");
    list.add("in order to — okay, you");
    list.add("know what, we don't care.");
    list.add("We were thinking of not even");
    list.add("doing this one.");

    int largestLineLength = 0;

    for (String s : list) {
        int length = s.length();
        if (length > largestLineLength) {
            largestLineLength = length;
        }
    }

    List<String> outputs = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String s : list.subList(0, list.size() - 1)) {

        int needSpace = largestLineLength - s.length();
        if (needSpace > 0) { //check if we need space in this line.
            String[] words = s.split(" "); //find words in the line
            int index = 0;

            StringBuilder[] stringBuilders = new StringBuilder[words.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < words.length - 1; i++) {
                stringBuilders[i] = new StringBuilder(words[i]);
                stringBuilders[i].append(" ");
            }

            stringBuilders[words.length - 1] = new StringBuilder(words[words.length - 1]);

            while (needSpace > 0) { //add spaces and decrease needSpace until it reaches zero.
                stringBuilders[index].append(" "); //add space to the end of every world in order
                index = index == words.length - 2 ? 0 : index + 1; //words-2 is because we didnt want any spaces after last word of line.
                needSpace--;
            }

            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
                stringBuilder.append(stringBuilders[i]);
            }


            s = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
        outputs.add(s);
    }
    outputs.add(list.get(list.size()-1));

    for(String s : outputs){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

---

```
Luke  Skywalker  has  returned
to his home planet of Tatooine
in   order   to  —  okay,  you
know   what,  we  don't  care.
We  were  thinking of not even
doing this one.
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is the find the exact number of spaces needed.

Then you can do a variation of the Bresenham algorithm to calculate the number of spaces to insert after each word without resorting to floating point arithmetic. There are `numberofWords - 1` spaces between words, so:

```
nSpaces / (numberofWords - 1 - wordPos)
```

Count the number of spaces already inserted (`nPad`) and insert

```
nSpaces / (numberofWords - 1 - wordPos) - nPad
```

spaces after the current word.

I'm sure there is a more elegant way to get it done, but as an initial version:

```
    final String[] lines = {
        "Luke Skywalker has returned",
        "to his home planet of Tatooine",
        "in order to — okay, you",
        "know what, we don't care.",
        "We were thinking of not even",
        "doing this one."
    };

    int maxLength = 0;
    for (String line: lines) {
        maxLength = Math.max(line.length(), maxLength);
    }

    final List<String> paddedLines = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String line: lines) {
        String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
        int wordsLength = 0;
        for (String word: words) {
            wordsLength += word.length();
        }
        int nSpaces = maxLength - wordsLength;

        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int nPad = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) {
            String word = words[i];
            sb.append(word);
            if (i < words.length - 1) {
                sb.append(' ');
                ++nPad;
                for (; nPad <= (nSpaces / (words.length - 1 - i)); ++nPad) {
                    sb.append(' ');
                }
            }
        }
        paddedLines.add(sb.toString());
    }
```

The suffers from some distribution issues, but seems to get the job done:

```
Luke   Skywalker has   returned
to  his home planet of Tatooine
in   order to —  okay,      you
know   what, we don't     care.
We  were thinking of not   even
doing         this         one.
```

To get an even nicer experience, we can use proper rounding instead of integer division:

```
            for (; nPad <= Math.round(nSpaces / (double)(words.length - 1 - i)); ++nPad) {
                sb.append(' ');
            }
```

This yields

```
Luke   Skywalker has   returned
to  his home planet of Tatooine
in   order to —  okay,      you
know   what, we  don't    care.
We  were thinking of not   even
doing          this        one.
```

Still not perfect, but better.

Comment: Line 3 & 4 are unchanged.

Comment: @Sorter What do you mean? I don't like the results in line 3 and 4, because they show of the problems that occur because of integer floor division.